# Prove/disprove that $f(\mathbf{v})= \|\mathbf{a}\|+\|\mathbf{v}-\mathbf{a}\|-\|\mathbf{v}\|$ is quasi-concave.

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a function which is defined as $f(\mathbf{v})= \|\mathbf{a}\|+\|\mathbf{v}-\mathbf{a}\|-\|\mathbf{v}\|$ where, $\mathbf{v} \in \mathbb{R}^2$ and $\mathbf{a} \in \mathbb{R}^2$ is any constant.
Prove/disprove that the function is quasi-concave.

Note: I have prove that this function is not concave.

My attempt:

assuming it is quasi-concave, we have,

$$
f(\lambda \mathbf{v}_1 + (1-\lambda)\mathbf{v}_2) \geq \min({f(\mathbf{v}_1),f(\mathbf{v}_2)})\\
\|\mathbf{a}\|+\|\lambda \mathbf{v}_1 + (1-\lambda)\mathbf{v}_2-\mathbf{a}\| - \|\lambda \mathbf{v}_1 + (1-\lambda)\mathbf{v}_2\| \geq \min({f(\mathbf{v}_1),f(\mathbf{v}_2)})\\
\|\mathbf{a}\|+\|\lambda (\mathbf{v}_1-\mathbf{a}) + (1-\lambda)(\mathbf{v}_2-\mathbf{a})\| - \|\lambda \mathbf{v}_1 + (1-\lambda)\mathbf{v}_2\| \geq \min({f(\mathbf{v}_1),f(\mathbf{v}_2)})
$$

I don't know how to proceed after this to arrive at any contradiction or tautology.

Comment: MO copy: [Prove/disprove that $f(\mathbf{v})= \|\mathbf{a}\|+\|\mathbf{v}-\mathbf{a}\|-\|\mathbf{v}\| $ is quasi-concave](https://mathoverflow.net/q/287180)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have the following:

1. $f(0) = 2 \lVert a \rVert$
2. $f(a) = 0$
3. $f(a + \varepsilon) = \lVert a \rVert + \lVert \varepsilon \rVert - \lVert a + \varepsilon \rVert > 0 $ by triangle inequality.

Since a point between $0$ and $a + \varepsilon$ has lower value than the end-points, the function is NOT quasi-concave.